# when radio button is selected, a popup box should display the text of the radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 radio buttons : Red, Blue and green 
When I select one of the three radio buttons, a popup box (alert) should appear and should display the text of the selected radio button (example : Blue). Can anyone please provide the javascript code for the it.
Thank You

Sorry about that, Here's what I tried regarding the javascript code:

```
function radioEvent (radio) 
{
var dom = document.getElementById("myForm");
  for (var index = 0; index < dom.radioButton.length;index++) 
  {
    if (dom.radioButton[index].checked) 
    {
      radio = dom.radioButton[index].value;
    }
  }
}


<td rowspan = "2" >
<input type="radio" name= "radioButton" value= "radio1"> Excellent<br>
<input type="radio" name="radioButton"  value="radio2" > Very Good <br>
<input type="radio" name="radioButton"  value="radio3" > Good <br>
<input type="radio" name="radioButton"  value="radio4" > Satisfactory
        </td>
```

My question is What to do next? I am confused...

Comment: What have you done so far? If you have anything, post it here and we'll try to help you work through it.

Comment: If you are going to use this site, you should be posting the errors to your code, not asking for people to do things for you.

Comment: At least a concise version of your html should be posted. **concise** and well formatted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function radioEvent(form) 
{
 for (var i = 0; i < form.radioButton.length; i++) 
 {
    if (form.radioButton[i].checked)
    {
        alert("You chose " + form.radioButton[i].value + ".")
    }
 }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="radio" name= "radioButton" value= "Excellent"   onclick="radioEvent(this.form);"/> Excellent<br/>
<input type="radio" name="radioButton"  value="Very Good" onclick="radioEvent(this.form);"/> Very Good <br/>
<input type="radio" name="radioButton"  value="Good" onclick="radioEvent(this.form);"/> Good <br/>
<input type="radio" name="radioButton"  value="Satisfactory" onclick="radioEvent(this.form);"/> Satisfactory
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the above code.Is it the same procedure for drop-down box, check box and text input too?

Answer (score 1):

I am just writing the HTML code:

```
<input id="a1" type="radio" name="group1" value="Red" onclick="alert('Red');">red <br>
<input id="a2" type="radio" name="group1" value="Blue" onclick="alert('Blue');" > Blue<br>
<input id="a3" type="radio" name="group1" value="Green" onclick="alert('Green');"> green
```

If you need any more code just let me know.

Comment: Thank You, but I need to do it using javascript

Comment: Is there a way to do the above using javascript? Thank You